# Minimal one condition must be fulfilled

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean, logic, conditional-statements

I have three form value and must be have minimal 1 of them should be fulfilled. What's the logic?

```
var form1 = "value"
var form2 = ""
var form3 = ""
```

How can i check all of them using boolean condition? Or else that might work?

Comment: form1 || form2 || form3

Comment: Define "fulfilled". What do they need to contain?

Comment: @tadman anything. That should not be an empty string.

Comment: What about just spaces or a tab? What about the string `"0"`?

Comment: What have you tried? The obvious answer is checking the length of each one...

Answer (score 0):

NVM, I just move the condition block. At first, I just want to make it after the condition block something like

```
if (condition_not_fulfilled) {
    return error
}
// the rest of logic continue...
```

And now I must use this,

```
if (form1 != "" || form2 != "" || form3 != "") {
    // logic inside here
}
return error
```